# canonical isomorphism $Y\times_{Y\times_Z Y}X\times_Z X\overset{\sim}\longrightarrow X\times_Y X$

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

> How is the canonical isomorphism defined here ?

$Y\times_{Y\times_Z Y}X\times_Z X\overset{\sim}\longrightarrow X\times_Y X$

additionally given are the maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$ both being separated morphisms. I don’t know whether this is necessary or not

here it is line $8$ from top

[image]

Comment: Some context would be appreciated, but these sorts of things usually follow from the universal properties (and therefore hold in any category).

Comment: user45878 this comes up in the proof of a theorem where $f$ and $g$ are separated morphisms as above and the aim is to show their composition is also separated.

Comment: I assume you're talking about Proposition 10.1.13. of Vakil, where he refers to exercise 1.3.S, which is purely an exercise in category theory. For this, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80797/magic-square-of-fibered-products-vague-unclear

Comment: Is it the same as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778186/the-magic-diagram-is-cartesian) ?